# Jira Automation Add Customer As Reporter

Tags: jira, ticket-system, jira-automation

I need to add a new customer as a reporter to the jira service desk by parsing a contact form's description (or using the reply-to field) in an incoming emailed request. Does anyone know of a bypass for this?

My goal is to get the new customer on the ticket where a jira service desk agent can respond by just commenting via the portal or by responding to their email alone as they are added to the ticket upon creation (on another automation). I also posted this issue [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Service-Management/Add-Inactive-New-Customer-Via-Automation/qaq-p/2514872#M150978).

[image]

I have tried using Automation, but I get "inactive" user after I try to change the ticket reporter to the new customer I add. It works if I add the customer and manually change the reporter to the new customer but I don't want to do anything manually. It also works fine if a new customer emails the service desk Atlassian email directly. I tried re-fetch delays and didn't see any difference with them. Maybe there is an api point I can post to make this work?

Comment: One question, do you use User Directories? Because it is OK to getting an "inactive" user until you sync the directory; since it is a new user. But after the sync done it should be valid. Can you check that?

Comment: I am speaking of inactive customers and not really users/agents. I did checkout what you're saying at https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/configuring-user-directories-938847049.html. I didn't see any very useful items there (like most of their docs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reaching out to Atlassian support, the formal answer is you have to perform a delayed web request and check the "*Delay execution of subsequent rule actions until we've received a response for this web request*" checkbox after adding the customer but before updating the reporter to allow time in fully adding the customer. Also, when you update the reporter, you must use the smart tag {{customer.accountId}} and not an email/other parameter.

Hope this helps someone!

[image]